# How to map the nested field in a collection to go struct that is not nested in format?

Tags: mongodb, go, struct

Format of bson:

```
{
  name: "root", 
  sports:" Cricket", 
  Personal: {
     age:32
  }
}
```

Go struct format:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `bson:"name"`
    Age  int `bson:"age"`
}
```

How to bind the value of age into this struct format in golang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an intermediate type that will help you transform your database DTO (Data Transform Object) into model object. It is recommended to separate those two.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type PersonInfoDto struct {
    Age int `json:"age"`
}

type PersonDto struct {
    Name     string        `json:"name"`
    Sports   string        `json:"sports"`
    Personal PersonInfoDto `json:"Personal"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    jsonInput := "{ \"name\": \"root\", \"sports\": \"Cricket\", \"Personal\": { \"age\": 32 }}"
    var dto PersonDto
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonInput), &dto)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // your model object
    p := Person{dto.Name, dto.Personal.Age}
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it will work. I had one more small doubt. What if the requested format changed after it moved to production? Before this realese, documents were without nested documents and after this realese it will be nested. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Instead of resolving the response into a specific structure you could store it into a map (key-value pairs) and decide in your application what to do if certain fields exists or not.